# Python Searching and removing an item plus the following two from a text file

Tags: python

I am just starting out with programming and am learning Python. I am having some troubles searching and removing from a text file. The text file contains a list of single spaced names. I need to have the user input a name and have it and the two following items removed from list.

Right now I am able to find and remove the searched for name and write the new `list` to the text file but I can't figure out how to remove the next two items. I tried using `list.index` to get the position of the searched for name but it gives the location of the first letter in the name. Is there a way that I can search the input word and get the location of the whole word `('bob','tom','jill') (0,1,2)` and use this to do what I need done?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide some code examples, as well as an excerpt from the input file so that the community can assist you.

Comment: the text file contains contacts.

Superman
5556874
Metropolis
Batman
5556987
Gotham

This is after having opened, read the contents and closed the file.

x = str(raw_input('Enter Name of Contact to Delete: '))
try:
   f = open(contacts, "w")
   for line in lines:
       mylist = line.split()
     
       if x in mylist:
           mylist.remove(x)

       s=""
       for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
           s= s+ mylist[i]+ '\n'
       f.write(s)
    f.close()

I tried,

if x in mylist:
    mylist.index(x)

But a search for batman would return 25 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contacts file is three lines per contact, an example file might look like this:

```
Fred
58993884
AnyTown
Mary
61963888
SomeCity
Bill
78493883
OtherTown
Anne
58273854
AnyCity
```

Script:

```
x = raw_input('Enter Name of Contact to Delete: ')

# do a case-insensitive match for names
target = x.strip().lower()

# create a list of all valid contacts
skip = False
contacts = []
with open('contacts.txt', 'r') as stream:
    for index, line in enumerate(stream):
        # check every third line
        if not index % 3:
            skip = (line.strip().lower() == target)
            if skip:
                print 'Removed Contact:', line
        if not skip:
            contacts.append(line)

# re-open the contacts file for writing
with open('contacts.txt', 'w') as stream:
    stream.write(''.join(contacts))
```

Output:

```
$ python2 /home/baz/code/misc/test.py
Enter Name of Contact to Delete: Mary
Removed Contact: Mary

$ cat contacts.txt 
Fred
58993884
AnyTown
Bill
78493883
OtherTown
Anne
58273854
AnyCity
```

Comment: Thanks. My file is 3 lines per contact.

Comment: @SJC. Updated my answer to fit your new spec. If this still doesn't match the structure of your contacts file, please amend your question with the full spec.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manipulating the list string of the names it would be better to manipulate a list of string names. You can easily convert the "big string" into a list using [string.split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
names_string = 'john robert jimmy'
names_list = names_string.split(' ') # names_list = ['john', 'robert', 'jimmy']
```

Now, you can easily add, remove or search names in this list, using basic list functions:

```
names_list.append('michael') # names_list = ['john', 'robert', 'jimmy', 'michael']
names_list.remove('robert') # names_list = ['john', 'jimmy', 'michael']
jimmy_position = names_list.index('jimmy') # jimmy_position = 1
```

Remember handling the exceptions when the element is not in the list.

To convert the list of names into a "big string" again, you can use [string.join](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
names_string = ' '.join(names_list)
```

Comment: Thanks. That works when I try it alone. I am having trouble getting it to work with what I had so far though. If I alter the split I already had I get no response. When I try to split the list again into a new list I get "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'". 


    x = str(raw_input('Enter Name of Contact to Delete: '))

    try:
        f = open(contacts, "w")
        for line in lines:
            mylist = line.split(' ')

            if x in mylist:
                y = mylist.index(x)